# Editing theme's less files doesn't reflect in the website

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm new to Magento. I have recently purchased a Magento theme from Themeforest, I found that there are no .css files there, instead there are only .less files, so I edited them but nothing happens in the website, nothing at all!
 Is there any specific command I have to run?

 And what is the right way to edit theme's stylesheet in Magento?
- Magento v2.2.3
- **Mode:** Default Mode.

Answer (score 0):

yes there are few commands to run in order to reflect the changes :

in comamnd line on your magento root run below command :

```
rm -rf ./pub/static/frontend ./pub/static/adminhtml ./var/view_processed/pub

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: It says : NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.
  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f'

Comment: Should I run it with (force mode?)

Comment: yes, i have updated command

Comment: The deployment ran successfully but nothing happened.. Changes did not reflect.

Comment: in which file are you making changes ? this command will compile your less file code

Comment: I'm making changes in the less file code

Comment: which less file is it ? could you name it.. because command provided here should compile all less, unelss you are making changes in wrong less..

Answer (score 0):

To reflect the changes of css files you have to do following steps.
Install node.js to any location on your machine.

Install Grunt CLI tool globally. To do this, run the following command in a command prompt:

> npm install -g grunt-cli

Install (or refresh) the node.jsproject dependency, including Grunt, for your Magento instance. To do this, run the following commands in a command prompt:

> cd  npm install npm update

Add your theme to Grunt configuration. To do this, in the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` file, add your theme to `module.exports` like following:

```
module.exports = { ... <theme>: { area: 'frontend', name: '<Vendor>/<theme>', locale: '<language>', files: [ '<path_to_file1>', //path to root source file '<path_to_file2>' ], dsl: 'less' ... },
```

Where the following notation is used:

`<theme>`: your theme code, conventionally should correspond to the theme directory name.

`<language>`: specified in the 'code_subtag' format, for example `en_US`. Only one locale can be specified here. To debug the theme with another locale, create one more theme declaration, having specified another value for language

`<path_to_file>`: path to the root source file, relative to the `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme/>web` directory. You need to specify all root source files of the theme. If your theme inheritsfrom a certain theme, and does not contain its own root source files, specify the root source files of the parent theme.

(Optional) If you want to use Grunt for "watching" changes automatically, without reloading pages in a browser each time, install the LiveReload extension in your browser

There are grunt commands which will useful.

> grunt exec: grunt less: PHP bin/magento s:s:d - f

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html refer this for more in detail

Comment: I'll follow this answer and let you know what happens. Thanks